# How to send a JQuery Variable to another PHP page via dblclick()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, listbox

So guys, I made a listbox and if I dblclick to an item the value of it gets saved into "val", but I can't send it to the next PHP File. I also alerted "val" - the value is really saved in it. I also get the function succes displayed in the browser console. what to do?
thanks

My Function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("option").dblclick(function () {

        var lb = document.getElementById("liste");
        var val = lb[lb.selectedIndex].value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'about.php',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            data: {
                aufid: val
            },
            success: function (data) {}
        });
    });
});
```

PHP Code in about.php:

```
 $id = $_POST['aufid'];
```

Comment: If you want to send the variables to about.php you're better of using a HTML form (method=post), and submitting the form with `$('#your-form').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to see what variables are in the `$_POST` superglobal?

`print_r($_POST);`

Comment: I can't because the doubleclick doesnt send me to the next page. I tried with windows.location but this does'nt work. Do I have to set the type of the Lsitbox Items to type="submit"? Or in the <select> tag of the listbox?

Comment: The `$.ajax` call won't get you to an other page. It requests a page without having to refresh your current page and you can use the data (json or html for example) in your current page. It is `window.location = 'http://google.com';` `windows.location` is not gonna work.

Comment: Hey I fixed the problem. Seems like I didn't understand how Ajax works at first. As you said I loose all the data if I refresh the page, I just have to send the data into a value of a html tag on the same page where the function is. The data includes the echo of about.php

Answer (score 0):

try to set the url your full adrees

```
url: 'http://myadress.com/about.php',
```

java script is running on your local computer so it might send the request to you own pc where no about.php exist

Comment: No, I'm running these files on a server and I also tried the full url. It doesn't work.